# re-uploading files when django form fails at some point

Tags: django, django-forms

Am currently working with django and using the forms to render a form different fields. The problem am facing is that I have file field in the form and sometimes when submitting the form and a different field returns an error, the file field "value" disappear, which means must re-select the file again..

Is there a way to maintain the file even when the form returns an error? Any examples I can look at or anything that can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you have sample codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/un1t/django-file-resubmit

> In Django project you have forms with FileField, ImageField.
>   Everything works great, but when ValidationError is raised, you have
>   to reselect all files and images again. It is kind of annoying.
>   django-file-resubmit solves this problem. It works with FileField,
>   ImageField and sorl.thumbnail.ImageField.